# Pinterest PinUtils variable not created on pinit.js exec

Tags: javascript, pinterest

In [official cookbook](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/pin-it/) of Pinterest I read:

> Including pinit.js gives you a global variable, PinUtils.
>
> PinUtils.pinOne() -- This function opens the Pin Create form [...] to saving an image you have chosen from your site.

I tried to call this function:

```
PinUtils.pinOne({ 'media': 'http://dcstat.ru/facades/img/fasad_565f0f8558ff1.jpeg' })
```

But seems like there was no PinUtils variable created on pinit.js execution.

Please, take a look at [jsFeedle](http://jsfiddle.net/vatavale/8tvf4snn/1/).

Comment: As per the official cookbook it needs to be PinUtils.pinOne({ 'media' ...

Provide a more functional jsfiddle to test this.

Comment: )) Done. But with no difference of course.

Comment: Looks like in source code of pinit.js on [GitHub](https://github.com/pinterest/widgets/blob/master/pinit_main.js) there is no one mention of PinUtils or it methods from docs. Does it means that docs are obsolete?